# Drawing rectangles for sorting visualizer?

Tags: java, algorithm, swing, sorting, user-interface

I am attempting to draw rectangles on a canvas that will represent items in a sorting visualizer.  I'm really having trouble coming up with an effective way to draw the rectangles proportionately side-by-side on my canvas (centered on my content pane by border layout) to be sorted by various algorithms.  I've done some research but haven't really found anything to point me in the right direction.  How can they even be moved effectively when the sorting occurs?  I suspect each rectangle will be an independent object to be sorted, probably just using the rectangle's height, but how are these objects drawn and moved in relation to one another?  Any advice is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Try taking a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756210/java-multiple-graphics/15756352#15756352)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example provided by MadProgrammer was the most helpful.