# Step By Step Code Execution as JButton Clicked

Tags: java, oop, user-interface, netbeans

I am making an application which graphically represents the SORTING techniques STEP by STEP.

How it works:

> USER clicks 'RELOAD' button , then clicks 'START' button atlast when
>   sorting start user click 'NEXT' again and again until the sorting end.

Problem:

**I am having problem how to make it possible for NEXT to do one thing and then wait for other click to do the work. Actually i want to know any function to handle or count the clicks happened. or any other way to do that**.

Please help... if you can. THANKS.

Comment: That's not as easy as it sounds  most sort algorithms are not presented in a "step by step" way that stores the current state and can be "paused" and "restated". You're really going to need to understand how the algorithms work. You can check out [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756210/java-multiple-graphics/15756352#15756352), which attempts to animate different algorithms

Comment: can u explain clearly.

Comment: I get what you trying to do.Are you stuck somewhere?You need to just put some waiting function into loop/algorithm that you running so each time you loop thru and *sort* element it will wait till you click a button.Bud i dont know what kind of sorting you do.Pretty much what MadProgrammer sayd it can get complicated.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I want to do some basic sorting techniques. like insertion sort , bubble sort the example done in java applet is here:
[link] http://www.cs.oswego.edu/~mohammad/classes/csc241/samples/sort/Sort2-E.html()

I know the basics of all sorting. just i want help in java code to stop and then start again the code execution. 

Thanks for your time!

Comment: @Abrar Check the link I supplied.  This basically makes two sort algorithms, bubble and insert that are controllable (or at least can notify the UI) that they have begin updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute each action into one thread. There is a thread.wait() method in Java that can freeze a thread  which is waiting for another action to be started and then use thread.start() to resume the job! I hope it can help!

Comment: Can you please give me link / tutorial explaining this. ? thanks alot.

Comment: You can search on youtube "Java Multi-Threading tutorial". there are a lot of examples there!