# Using a timer for my visually updating bar graph

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have been having trouble with getting my timer to show my bar graph updating itself over time instead, what I have is my graph being sorted automatically even though I set the timer to update every couple of seconds. 
Here are my paint and `updatetextfieldthread` method.

```
private class Display extends JPanel    {
        private Color color = Color.RED;

 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        Dimension d = getPreferredSize();
        int clientWidth = d.width;
        int clientHeight = d.height;
        int barWidth = clientWidth / array.length;
        int x=0, y=0;
        int base=410;
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
             x+=30;
             y+=30;
            int linethickness=20;
            int linelength=50;
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.fillRect(x, base-linelength*array[i], linethickness , linelength*array[i]);
                g.setColor(Color.black);
                g.drawRect(x, base-linelength*array[i], linethickness, linelength*array[i]);

        }
 }
 }
 private class UpdateTextFieldThread extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer> 
    {
        static final int THREAD_DELAY = 1000;
        protected Void doInBackground()
        {
             ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            try {
                Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        insertionSort(array);
                        display.repaint();
                    }
                };
                Future<?> f = service.submit(r);

                f.get(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES); 
            }
                catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                    // The thread was interrupted during sleep, wait or join
                }
                catch (final TimeoutException e) {
                    // Took too long!
                }
                catch (final ExecutionException e) {
                    // An exception from within the Runnable task
                }
                finally {
                    service.shutdown();
                }
            return null;



        }


        protected void process(java.util.List<Integer> list)
        {
            textfield.setText("" + list.get(list.size() - 1));
        }
    }
```

now revised: I'm breaking down my sorting method step by step and I am updating the thread inside of it but it is still not breaking down my graph.

```
private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
         Object src = e.getSource();
         if (src == button1){

           int[] array2=array;
           for (int i = 1; i < array2.length; i++) {
                int thingToInsert = array2[i];

                int j = i - 1;
                while (j >= 0 && thingToInsert<array2[j]) {
                array2[j+1] = array2[j];
                j--;
                }

                array2[j+1] = thingToInsert;
                (new UpdateTextFieldThread()).execute();
            }

         }
         }
}


 private class UpdateTextFieldThread extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer> 
    {
         static final int THREAD_DELAY = 1000;
         protected Void doInBackground()
        {
             ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecuto();
            try {
                Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
            Thread.sleep(THREAD_DELAY);
            display.repaint();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                   }
                };
                Future<?> f = service.submit(r);

                f.get(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES); 
            }
                catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                    // The thread was interrupted during sleep, wait or join
                }
                catch (final TimeoutException e) {
                    // Took too long!
                }
                catch (final ExecutionException e) {
                    // An exception from within the Runnable task
                }
                finally {
                    service.shutdown();
                }
            return null;




        }
```

Comment: You `insertionSort` method isn't staged/stepped, once the method returns, the sort has been completed, therefore, there is nothing to update...

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756210/java-multiple-graphics/15756352#15756352)...Remember, animation is the illusion of change over time.  Therefore, each time you `run` method is called, you need to move to the next state.  Also, this is not a particularly good approach...I'd consider a Swing `Timer` instead, so long as you could re-work your `insertionSort` method to be stepped in instead of a whole sort.  See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: You are returning `null` but the return type is Void?

Comment: Ok well I tried using timer a lot but couldn't really get it to work but I have almost got what I was looking for using threads. I'm only missing one line I think and I feel like its on the tip of my tongue now. I've been getting my graph to pause using thread delay but it still misses the step where it shows it in steps and I have moved the insertion sort code to the actionevent method now and I'm calling the thread from within in the method but yet it still refuses to act right...I'm going to keep messing with it but any help is appreciated (I posted a little of it above).