# Getting a position in a JTextArea and using a timer

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm working on a school project and I'm hoping if you guys could help me. 
I have this:

```
JTextArea processTxt = new JTextArea();
```

And when I press this button,

```
JButton sortBtn = new JButton("SORT!");
```

This would display this on `processTxt`.

```
   public void sort(String type, String order, int size) {
            int tempInt, int1, int2;
            processTxt.append("Pass 0:\n");
            for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
                if (type.equals("int")) {
                    processTxt.append(intList.get(i)+" ");
                }
            }
            processTxt.append("\n");
            for (int i=0; i<size-1; i++) {
                int x=0;
                processTxt.append("Pass "+(i+1)+": \n");
                while (x<size-1) {
                    int y = x + 1;
                    if (type.equals("int")) {
                        int1 = intList.get(x);
                        int2 = intList.get(y);
                        if (order.equals("asc")) {
                            if (int1 >= int2) {
                                tempInt = int1;
                                intList.set(x, int2);
                                intList.set(y, int1);
                            }
                        }
                        else if (order.equals("desc")) {
                            if (int1 <= int2) {
                                tempInt = int1;
                                intList.set(x, int2);
                                intList.set(y, int1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    for (int z=0; z<size; z++) {
                        if (type.equals("int")) {
                            processTxt.append(intList.get(z)+" ");
                        }
                    }
                    processTxt.append("\n");
                    x++;
                }
            }
            processTxt.append("Sorted:\n");
            for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
                if (type.equals("int")) {
                    processTxt.append(intList.get(i)+" ");
                }
            }
        }
```

I was thinking:

1. How could I get the position of `int1`  on the text area?
2. Is there any way that I could use a timer to delay the output on the text area? I have used `thread.sleep()` but it won't work.

Comment: 1) *"Getting a position in a JTextArea and using a timer"*  SO is not a help desk, but a Q&A site.  As such, each question should be asked on it's own thread.  2) Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) how could i get int1's position on the textarea;

Apart from physically searching the text, you could maintain reference to the location that it would have been inserted, before you inserted.

You could use the `JTextArea`'s caret position if you are inserting text at the current cursor position, otherwise, you will need to determine the index point from within the `Document` you are updating.

> 2) is there any way that i could use a timer to delay the output on the textarea? i have used thread.sleep() but it wont work.

Yes, but understand, this becomes increasingly more complex.

You could use a Swing `Timer` which will would trigger a callback at a regular interval, allowing you to update state of the sort and update the UI.  This is useful as it triggers the callback within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, making it safe to update the UI from within.

It does, how ever, increase the complexity, as the `Timer` acts as a kind of pseudo loop.

You could use a `SwingWorker` instead.  This would allow you to take your current code and run it within the `doInBackground` method, which is executed outside of the Event Dispatching Thread, allowing you to use `Thread.sleep` to inject a delay where you want them without affecting the UI.

The problem is, you will need to use the `SwingWoker`s `publish`/`process` methods to push updates to the UI, this disconnects the time you make a change to the model to the time it appears in the UI, which may present issues with determining the location that a given update should occur (within the context of your first question).

Take a look at:

- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
- [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

for more details

Comment: so, i'd put the whole code in doInBackground? or just the code when i press the button? thanks BTW..

Comment: In theory, you could call `sort` from `doInBackground`, but then `sort` would not be able to update the UI directly, it would require an instance of the `SwingWorker` in order to be able to sync the updates back to the UI (or get messy with `SwingUtiltiies.invokeLater`)

Comment: okay.. i'll study on that later.. about my first question, do the caret position move when a text is appended? like when typing, the caret moves as you type. does it behave like that when you append text on a TextArea?

Comment: Yes, the caret position determines where the next insertion will occur.  You can insert directly into the underlying `Document` by using the `Document` directly...

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my questions.. been reading some SwingWorker articles.. can you explain why cant i update the UI if i just plug in sort() in doInBackground()?

Comment: Last one.. so i would call sort() on doInBackground(), then i would call process.append() in publish()?

Comment: Only if `sort` was capable of doing it.  Once you call `sort`, you lose control.  Another idea might be to use a `step` method, which can return information about what occurred or `null` (or some such) when it's finished.  This way, you would be able to call `step`, use `publish` to push updates to the UI (which are handled by `process`) until `step` returns some kind of "completed" state.  This way, you can control the time between steps yourself...

Comment: This is kind of the idea [presented in this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756210/java-multiple-graphics/15756352#15756352)