# How to make buttons glow while iterating through array of buttons?

Tags: java, swing, thread-sleep

I would like to display how linear search works visually. 
I have created and ADT class of just integers. I also have a frame with buttons on it, when  I hit the fillButton, it generates an array of random integers which are displayed on an array of buttons.
When i hit the findButton it will look for the specific number entered. As i am iterating through the array, i would like to make corresponding button change color.

I had created a similar program that iterated through an array of buttons, and changed the color as it went through. I had used Thread.sleep(), and it was just the main class. This time i have two classes and i am not sure how to go about it. I dont't know how to go about making a connection between the ADT class and the GUI class. I've used EventObjects and custom EventListeners before, but that was merely to store objects. Any help pointing in the right direction is appreciated. Thank you.

This is part of the ADT class

```
public class ADT {
private int[] a;
private int nElems;
private int SIZE = 60;

public ADT(){
    a = new int[SIZE];
    nElems=0;
}
public void initialPlacement(int index, int value,int initialCount){
    a[index] = value;
    nElems = initialCount;
}
public int linearSearch(int searchKey){
    int index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < nElems; i++){
        if(getVal(i) == searchKey){
            index = i;
            break;
        }
        else{
            index = -1;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

And here is part of the GUI class

```
public NumberFrame(){///CONSTRUCTOR===========================
        arr = new ADT();
        //CREATE COMPONENTS
        for(int i = 0; i < 60; i++){
             listButtons[i] = new JButton(String.valueOf("_"));
         }
        for(int i = 0; i < 60; i++){
             listLabels[i] = new JLabel(String.valueOf("["+i+"]"));
         }
        for(int i = 0; i < 60; i++){
             listMiniPanels[i] = new JPanel();
             listMiniPanels[i].add(listLabels[i]);
             listMiniPanels[i].add(listButtons[i]);
         }
fillButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    boolean sort = true;
                    if(linearRadio.isSelected()){
                        System.out.println("linear is checked");
                        fill(!sort);//fills half the array and array of buttons with random numbers, unsorted
                    }else if(binaryRadio.isSelected()){
                        System.out.println("binary is checked");
                        fill(sort);//fills half the array with random numbers and sorts it
                    }else{
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please check a sorting method");
                    }
            }
        })
findButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                int index= 0;
                if(numberField.getText().equals("")){
                    System.out.print("Arr size = " + arr.size());
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You did not enter a number");

                }else {
                    try {
                        int searchKey = Integer.parseInt(numberField.getText());    
                        if(linearRadio.isSelected()){
                            index = arr.linearSearch(searchKey);
                            listButtons[index].setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                            if(index > -1)
                                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Found number " +searchKey + " @ index [" + index + "]");
                                else
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No such number");
                        }else{
                            index = arr.binarySearch(searchKey);
                            if(index > -1)
                                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Found number " + searchKey+ " @ index [" + index + "]");
                                else
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No such number!");
                        }
                      } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                          System.out.println("Arr size = " + arr.size());
                          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not an integer, pleas try again!");
                      } 
                }
            }   
        });
}//=======CONSTRUCTOR END=============================
```

Comment: Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).  You could use a `SwingWorker` or if you are really clever, a Swing `Timer`, [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756210/java-multiple-graphics/15756352#15756352) which is a conceptual implementation of a sort animation

Comment: *"Any help pointing in the right direction is appreciated."*  Given this is a Q&A site, the direction I would suggest is 'ask a question'. *"Thank you."*  No worries.

Comment: Those look helpful, thank you!