# Java - animate insertion sort using timers

Tags: java, swing, animation, timer, insertion-sort

I am currently working on a project for a visual representation of an Insertion Sort, where bars are moved graphically across the screen. However, I need to fire off a timer in between each command, without the use of the sleep method. Right now I have managed to make it sort, however, it is not going through every step. [Here is a GIF of my current project in action.](https://gfycat.com/HeartyScratchyAmericancurl)  I need to make the timer fire off for each step, repainting after each part of the algorithm. What are some of the ways I go about this?

```
public void insertSort(){
    if(i < data.length){
        for(int j = i; j > 0; j--){
            if(data[j] < data[j-1]){
                int temp = data[j];
                data[j] = data[j-1];
                data[j-1] = temp;
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }
    i++;
    timer.start();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(setColor);
    int xChange = 20;
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        if(data[i] != 0){
            g.fillRect(xChange,HEIGHT-data[i],10,data[i]);
            xChange = xChange + 20;
        }
    }
}
public class TimeListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        timer.stop();
        insertSort();
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean, something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756210/java-multiple-graphics/15756352#15756352)?  The essential idea is, each tick of the `Timer` is a iteration of the loop, so this means you need to modify you sort algorithm in such away so that the mechanism that drives it is separate from the logic (ie pass in the loop values to a method), this way you can drive the algorithm via different mechanisms

Comment: Yeah that's exactly it. Thank you.