# How to update Java Swing GUI using Timer and delay?

Tags: java, swing, sorting, user-interface, timer

I am trying to make a sorting visualizer using a Java GUI. The problem I'm facing is updating the GUI in real time. For instance, when I shuffle the initial array I will call the following  shuffle and swap methods. I expect it to repaint the GUI and then do it again after a delay but instead all it does is finish the shuffleArray method then repaints it all at once showing no "animation". What is a better way of going about this?

```
   public void shuffleArray() {
        final int milliDelay = 1000;
        for (int i = NUM_BARS - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            int rand = (int) (Math.random() * i);

            swap(i,rand, milliDelay);
        }
    }

    public void swap(int firstIndex, int secondIndex, int delay) {

        Timer timer = new Timer(delay, e -> {
            int temp = data[firstIndex];
            data[firstIndex] = data[secondIndex];
            data[secondIndex] = temp;

            barColors[firstIndex] = Color.RED;
            barColors[secondIndex] = Color.RED;

            repaint();

            barColors[firstIndex] = Color.WHITE;
            barColors[secondIndex] = Color.WHITE;
        });
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
    }
```

Comment: [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756210/java-multiple-graphics/15756352#15756352).  Consider providing a [mcve], it will provide better context and attract more help suggestions as to how to solve your particular problem

Comment: Ok, so immediately, they're a number of issues.  Your `shuffleArray` is calling `swap` which is creating n number of `Timer`s.  The problem with this is they will likely all be called within a close period of time of each other, resulting in an updated which may just look like it's jump to the end result.  Instead.  You need a single `Timer` that performs each step of the sort it self - that is, each time it's called, it will perform the swap.  The `Timer` will act a pseudo loop