# (java) - repaint() works in one method but doesn’t work in another

Tags: java

repaint() works in one method but not another

So, I am trying to create a visual sorting algorithm for a project. Basically I draw 150 2d lines on a panel and, initially they are drawn in sorted order. Then I press a button to scramble them and it works perfectly. It redraws all the lines in random order every time I press the button. I then implemented a sorting algorithm i tested in a different project first to make sure it worked and it does. However, when I tell my program to sort my list of lines nothing happens visually on the program. I used print statements to make sure my list is actually being sorted and it is. I don't understand why the repaint() method works in the scramble() method but it doesn't work in the BubbleSort() method. I'm pretty new to GUI building and i'm using Apache Netbeans if thats important. I'll post my code below.

```
    import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class mainJpanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form mainJpanel
     */
    ArrayList<Line> Mainlist = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Line> templist = new ArrayList<>();

   
     public mainJpanel() {
        initComponents();
        addLines(150);

    }

  
      public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawList(g);

    }

 
       public void drawList(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));
        for (Line l : Mainlist) {
            g2.drawLine(l.x1, l.y1, l.x2, l.y2);
        }
    }


        public void addLines(int s) {
        int size = s;

        int x1 = 800;
        int y1 = 300;
        int x2 = 800;
        int y2 = 600;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Mainlist.add(new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2));

            x1 -= 5;
            x2 -= 5;
            y1 += 2;
        }
    }


    public void scramble() {
        int x = 50;
        int rand = 0;
        int size = Mainlist.size();
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            rand = (int) (Math.random() * Mainlist.size());
            Mainlist.get(rand).setx1(x);
            Mainlist.get(rand).setx2(x);
            templist.add(Mainlist.get(rand));
            Mainlist.remove(rand);
            x += 5;
        }
        ResetLists();
        repaint(); // repaint works here
    }

    private void ResetLists() {
        for (int i = 0; i < templist.size(); i++) {
            Mainlist.add(templist.get(i));

        }
        templist.clear();

    }
    

    public void BubbleSort() {
        templist.add(new Line(0, 0, 0, 0));
        int swaps = 1;
        while (swaps > 0) {
            swaps = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < Mainlist.size(); i++) {
                if (Mainlist.get(i - 1).getYSize() > Mainlist.get(i).getYSize()) {
                    templist.set(0, Mainlist.get(i));
                    Mainlist.set(i, Mainlist.get(i - 1));
                    Mainlist.set(i - 1, templist.get(0));
                    swaps++;
                } else {
                    //nothing to swap
                }
            }

        }
        repaint(); // repaint does nothing here 
    }


    private void ScrambleButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        scramble();
    }   

 
    private void SortButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        BubbleSort();
    }
}
```

and below is the Line class I created to store Line objects in an ArrayList

```
public class Line {
    int x1;
    int y1;
    int x2;
    int y2;
    
    public Line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y2 = y2;
        
    }
    
    public void setx1(int x){
        this.x1 = x;
    }
    public void setx2(int x){
        this.x2 = x;
    }
    public int getYSize(){
        return Math.abs(this.y1 - this.y2);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, nothing will be repaint (or events handled) until the method exists. See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). You have two options, use a Swing `Timer` or a `SwingWorker`.  The `Timer` will give you more accurate control over when the UI is to be updated, but can make it more difficult to implement your logic. A `SwingWorker` will allow you to run your code outside of the EDT and sync updates back to the UI, but no guarantees that an update will be rendered before more changes are made

Comment: See [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details and [java multiple graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756210/java-multiple-graphics/15756352#15756352) for an example

Comment: Did you override `repaint()` in your code? I can tell there's definitely code you cut out from here but it would be tremendously useful to see your implementation of `repaint()`.

Comment: @guninvalid: it has nothing to do with "overriding repaint` or your incorrect (now deleted) answer. The problem is exactly as mad programmer has described it: the OP is blocking the event dispatch thread, and when this happens, this key thread can't do its important actions, including drawing the GUI and interacting with the user.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried implementing a timer to call repaint() every x seconds. However im still having the same issue as before. I removed all the other repaint() calls in my code except for where i added the repaint() call in my actionPerformed method. Maybe I am misunderstanding you answer?

Comment: Also, maybe i was not clear in my initial post. When I click my scramble button the ui ALWAYS updates. It updates before and after I press my sort button. I might be misunderstanding but if the method called by the sort button is blocking the EDT from updating the UI then why is it that scramble always updates the ui even after the sort is "blocking" it.